# I am trying to plot the individual data points along with box plots from two different data frames based on a condition using seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, jupyter-lab

I am using seaborn in Jupyterlab to plot my data. Here is the code snippet for plotting the graph where I have separated data based on the presence/absence of PMMA shown by PMMA=1, PMMA=0 respectively. However, the strip plot on PMMA=1 for 17 and 20 on the x-axis is plotting the individual data points from PMMA=0 and the strip plot for PMMA=0 is not showing for the rest of the data. How can I fix this issue? Also, the legend is not showing the tag as "Day#"

```
both = pd.concat((df1, df2))

grped_bplot = sns.catplot(x='Passage#', 
                          y='Dendrite Length (um)',
                          hue="Day#",
                          col="PMMA",
                          kind="box",
                          legend=False,
                          height=6, 
                          aspect=1.3,
                          palette="Set2",
                          data=both);
grped_bplot = sns.stripplot(x='Passage#', 
                            y='Dendrite Length (um)', 
                            hue='Day#',
                            jitter=True,
                            dodge=True, 
                            marker='o', 
                            palette="Set2",
                            alpha=0.5,
                            data=both)

handles, labels = grped_bplot.get_legend_handles_labels()
l = plt.legend(handles[0:3], labels[0:3])
```

Boxplot with overlapping strip plot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`sns.catplot` returns a `FacetGrid`.  You can call `.map_dataframe(sns.stripplot)` to create strip plots for the same data.

Here is some example code starting from generated test data:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# first, create some test data
both = pd.DataFrame({'Passage#': np.random.choice([6, 17, 18, 19, 20], 500),
                     'Dendrite Length (um)': np.random.uniform(1, 17, 500) ** 3,
                     'Day#': np.random.choice([3, 4, 7], 500),
                     'PMMA': np.random.randint(0, 2, 500)})
g = sns.catplot(x='Passage#',
                y='Dendrite Length (um)',
                hue="Day#",
                col="PMMA",
                kind="box",
                legend=False,
                height=6,
                aspect=1.3,
                palette="Set2",
                boxprops={'alpha': 0.4},
                data=both)
g.map_dataframe(sns.stripplot,
                x='Passage#',
                y='Dendrite Length (um)',
                hue='Day#',
                jitter=True,
                dodge=True,
                marker='o',
                palette="Set2",
                alpha=0.5)
g.add_legend(title='Day#')
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.catplot combined with sns.stripplot]

PS: To have the boxes in the legend instead of the dots, you can call `g.add_legend()` after the `catplot` but before calling `g.map_dataframe`.

Comment: If this answers your question, you might consider marking the question as accepted by clicking the checkmark, turning it from gray into green.